# Return integer from UserManager<ApplicationUser> as a Json

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I'am facing to return this Id value as Json from asp.net web api (Returning fron AspNetUsers table). Is this possible to return it as Json and then get it in Jquery? Right now I get null becouse maybe this returns not as Json. Thank you in advance!

```
public IHttpActionResult GetDepId()
        {
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            string name = User.Identity.Name;

            var depId = manager.Users.Where(d => d.Email == name).Select(c => c.DepartmentId).FirstOrDefault();
            return Ok(depId);
        }
```

and then in jquery:

```
function GetDept() {


            $.ajax({
                url: '/Api/userdp', // userdp is my controller
                type: 'GET',


                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    result; // failed even this result.Email; 
                },
                error:  {


                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you cant use `Ok()` like that. Try using `return new ObjectResult(depId);` in your controller instead.

EDIT: Yeah you can. You just need to serialize your output, or manually make the JSON object like so:

`return Ok(string.Format("id:{0}", depId.ToString()));`

Comment: thank you for your response, but I'am geting error Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'ObjectResult' When I return like this: return new ObjectResult(depId);  Or return Ok(new ObjectResult(depId));

Comment: Try `return new ObjectResult(new {id= depId});`

Comment: Thank you again but stil the same error message. Is this something with IHttpActionResult to do?

Comment: Alright, let's try something different. Try doing the following: `return Ok(string.Format("id:{0}", depId.ToString()));". Essentially we are manually creating a JSON object to return. In a real scenario you would use a serializer, but this is just for testing.

Comment: Thank you now I'am not geting any error but it returns "id:0" when I use postman, but when I debug I can see a value of deptId and it's deptId = 2. Please..please.. help.. you are almost done.. ;)

Comment: Do `string str = string.Format("id:{0}", depId.ToString()); return Ok(str);` and use the debugger to make sure we are creating the string correctly.

Comment: Very strange.. When I start project and debuging then it shows me dept = 2, but If I run postman and debuging it's id:0. So postman then debuging returns id:0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143009/discussion-between-sty-and-jonas-willander).